# Secure form using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple form with three input fields for posting messages into specific group:

- input for the text
- hidden field with group id
- hidden field with token

The submiting is done using Ajax and sending **input text** and **hidden fields**

What I do:
The text send by the user is validated.
I check if the token match with the session token created for that form.

The problem:
The hidden id (group id) can be changed by the user and post will insert into the wrong group.

I can remove the **hidden id** and get the **group id** from the session. But i'm not sure if this is secure

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is secured, session variables reside on the server not on the client side. Although, if the user can be under a certain group, you could query or look it up in the database upon submitting instead of saving it in the session. If you have other form or page that the user can access and change his/her group, then the group id in your session will be invalid.

Comment: Yes the user may open two groups and later post to the first one, but session of the group id = the second group. Which is wrong

Comment: If the user can be in several groups, you can still have a hidden group id on the form. You just need to query all group ids of the user and check if the posted group id is in those ids.

Comment: but the user can access all groups

Comment: Perhaps you are worrying that user might change the hidden groupid to anything he wants, let's just say 1 for superadmins. But as what I have said, you could just get all the user's group ids and check if it is in that list. You must control on how the user can join a group if that's a big concern. You may also need to do some complex validation if the groups have different privileges.